# How do I get a query to run in the DataGridView within Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to develop a windows form for SQL database. I have inserted a `DataGridView` and connected the datasource for the table I wish to display in the `DataGridView`. To populate the view I picked one of the tables I need data from.  However, I need to pull data from three different tables. So I clicked on the “Add Query…” link and built the query to retrieve the data from all three tables.

QUERY:

```
Select    TRN_Hist.EMplno, TRN_PERS.NAMELAST, ETC

from      TRN_COMM INNERJOIN
           TRN_HIST ON TRN_COMM.COMMNO = TRN_HIST.COMMO INNER JOIN
           TRN_PERS ON TRN_HIST.EMPLNO = TRN_PERS.EMPLNO
```

I ran the query and it pulled the data. However, when I click OK at the bottom of the pop up menu “search Criteria Builder” it returns the following error:

> "The schema returns by the new query differs from the base query."

It seems I can not build the query with the query builder. How do I get the query connected to the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView pulls the data from the DataSet Record. You need to build the query by going to the dataset screen and from the toolbox pull the TableAdapter and drop it into the Dataset Screen. Open the wizard and from there the query can be built. Then from the DataGridView box Choose Data Source  click other data sources and drop down further and pick the query that was created from the dataset screen.